# has_many :through, 3 way join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many-through

I have a Play that has many CostumedActors. A CostumedActor is a join of Actors and Costumes which have a many to many relationship.

This seems to be a pattern that should be quite common, but I'm not clear about the best way to do it in rails.

I have currently set it up as a 3-way join association as follows:

```
class Play < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :costumed_actors
  has_many :actors, :through => costumed_actors
  has_many :costumes,:through => costumed_actors
end

class CostumedActor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :play
  belongs_to :costume
  belongs_to :actor
end

class Costume < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :actors, :through => costumed_actors
  has_many :plays, :through => costumed_actors
end

class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :costumes, :through => costumed_actors
  has_many :plays, :through => costumed_actors
end
```

Rails doesn't handle this perfectly.  If I want to see the actors or costumes in a play, no problem:

```
play.costumes
play.actors
```

But if I want to see which costume an actor wears, I can't do

```
play.actors.costumes
```

In this case the .costumes gives me all the costumes each actor wears, across all plays, not just the current one.

I have to do something like:

```
play.costumed_actors.where(:actor => @actor).map {|x| x.costumes}
```

or more cleanly, by adding a helper method to the has_many :through association

```
class Play
  has_many :costumes, :through => costumed_actors do
    def for_actor(actor)
      where("costumed_actors.actor_id = ?", actor) if !actor.nil?
    end
  end
end

play.costumes.for_actor(@actor)
```

Also, adding associations doesn't work correctly.  I'd like to be able to do something like

```
Play.actors << actor.with_costume(costume)
```

But I can't see how to phase an association helper method, or even if that approach is possible.

Is this the best way to represent this scenario, and if so is this the best way to read/write the associated records?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Play
  has_many :actors_costumes, :through => :actors, :source => :costumes
end
```

You can get the actors costumes as follows:

```
play.actors_costumes
```

Comment: Thanks, but this appears to generate the exact same SQL as a simple `play.actors`  There are 3 relations, and for this kind of query I will need to specify 2 of them somehow, and get the third, as in my example `play.actors.with_costume(costume)`.  My larger question is really about the correct way to represent with 3-table join (perhaps more accurately described as many-many with a lookup table) in rails